# select multiple chosen in angularjs placeholder text issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have a dropdown. and i can select multiple option. but problem is due to multiple option i am unable change my default text. and default text showing like this. please see the image

[image]

and here is my html code:

```
 <select multiple required ng-change="StateChanged(user.ID)"  ng-model="answers" data-placeholder="Select Users" chosen="" class="chosen-select input-md"
                            ng-options="user.ID as user.EmployeeName + ' '+user.EmployeeLastName  for user in users">
                        <option disabled></option>
                    </select>
```

Please Help what should i do to fixed this issue

Comment: Can you create code snippet?

Comment: can you try by changing  `<option disabled></option>` to `<option value="">select</option>`?

Comment: #nikhil i was tried it showing as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Chosen and multi-select where my text was being cut off. The below worked for me.

CSS

```
.chosen-container .chosen-choices .search-field:only-child input {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```